# Swift: I want insert text into table cell and when a user enters the text, the view should navigate to the next view

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

This is my current code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")

    Catagory1.CategoryNo = indexPath.row + 1

    let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)

    let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SubView") as! SubCatagory


    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextViewController, animated:true)
    let backItem = UIBarButtonItem()
    backItem.title = "Back"
    backItem.tintColor? = UIColor.blueColor()
    navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backItem

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could possibly use the didEndEditing delegate method on the textField so that if they exit out of the text you can segue to that page. But other than the user leaving the text field, there is no real way to know when they are done entering text.

Another option is to directly make an Action connection from the text field by control + dragging to your view controller, and selecting action as the type and then selecting "did end editing". The one flaw I see to this is that the user has to leave the text field, which if there is only one may be misleading.

We might be better off answering the question if you provided more details about what your trying to do.